# For any sets $A,B,C$, $^{(A\times B)}C$ is equinumerous with $^{A}(^{B}C)$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Is this proof valid? Is it too informal? For example the function definitions are pretty informal i think, is that a bad thing?

**Theorem:** For any sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, the set of functions from $A \times B$ to $C$ has the same cardinality as the set of functions from $A$ to the set of functions from $B$ to $C$. That is, $^{A\times B}C \sim ^{A}(^{B}C)$.

**Proof:**

*Case 1:* One of the sets $A$, $B$, or $C$ is empty.

- If $A = \emptyset$, then both $^{A\times B}C$ and $^{A}(^{B}C)$ contain only the empty function, and hence have cardinality 1.
- If $B = \emptyset$, then $^{A\times B}C$ contains just the empty function and $^{A}(^{B}C)$ is the set of functions from $A$ to the empty function, which both have a cardinality of $1$.
- If $C = \emptyset$, then both $^{A\times B}C$ and $^{A}(^{B}C)$ are empty.

*Case 2:* None of the sets are empty.

Given a function $f: A\times B \to C$, we can associate it with a function $g: A \to ^{B}C$ such that for each $a \in A$, $g(a)$ is the function $h: B \to C$ defined by $h(b) = f(a,b)$.

**Injectivity:** Suppose $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two functions from $A\times B$ to $C$ that are associated with the same function $g: A \to ^{B}C$. Then for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $f_1(a,b) = f_2(a,b)$, which implies $f_1 = f_2$.

**Surjectivity:** Given any function $g: A \to ^{B}C$, we can construct a function $f: A\times B \to C$ such that for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $f(a,b) = g(a)(b)$. This function $f$ is then associated with $g$ under our correspondence.

Thus, we have established a bijection between $^{A\times B}C$ and $^{A}(^{B}C)$, proving the theorem.